# R How to web scrape data from StockTwits with RSelenium?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I want to get some information from tweets posted on the platform StockTwits.
Here you can see an example tweet: https://stocktwits.com/Kndihopefull/message/433815546
I would like to read the following information: Number of replies, number of reshares, number of likes:

[image]

I think this is possible with the `RSelenium`-package. However, I am not really getting anywhere with my approach.
Can someone help me?

```
library(RSelenium)

url<- "https://stocktwits.com/Kndihopefull/message/433815546"

# RSelenium with Firefox
rD <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(browser="firefox", port=4546L)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(url)
Sys.sleep(4)

# get the page source
web <- remDr$getPageSource()
web <- xml2::read_html(web[[1]])
```

I would like to have a list (or a data set) as a result, which looks like this:

```
$Reply
[1] 1

$Reshare
[1] 1

$Like
[1] 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get required info we can do,

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(RSelenium)
#launch browser
driver = rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"))
url = "https://stocktwits.com/ArcherUS/message/434172145"

remDr <- driver$client
remDr$navigate(url)


#First we shall get the tags

remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() %>% html_nodes('.st_3kvJrBm') %>% 
  html_attr('title') 
[1] "Reply"   "Reshare" "Like"    "Share"   "Search" 

#then the number associated with it
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() %>% html_nodes('.st_3kvJrBm') %>% 
  html_text()
[1] ""  ""  "2" ""  ""
```

The last two items `Share` and `Search` will be empty.

The faster approach would be by using `rvest`.

```
library(rvest)
url = "https://stocktwits.com/ArcherUS/message/434172145"

url %>% 
  read_html() %>% html_nodes('.st_3kvJrBm') %>% 
  html_attr('title') 

url %>% 
  read_html() %>% html_nodes('.st_3kvJrBm') %>% 
  html_text()
```

Comment: The result is `{xml_nodeset (0)}`. Somehow the function does not advance. =/

Comment: Revised the answer, hope it works.

Comment: Yes now I have the same result. Thanks for that.

Comment: However, it does not say what exactly the number is assigned to. For example, for posts with only 1 Like, no Reply and no Reshare, there is only a `"1"`. But I can't assign this number exactly to the Like, Reply or Reshare. Better would be an output, which I suggested in my question. Here is an example `url = "https://stocktwits.com/ArcherUS/message/434172145"`

Comment: Revised the answer.

Comment: Great job! Many thanks for this solution.